# Property folder in payload has a value that does not match schema

Tags: azure, api, onedrive, zoho, zoho-deluge

the graph API request to create a folder in one drive is

POST /me/drive/root/children
Content-Type: application/json

My code:

```
callMap = Map();
callMap.putAll({"name":"New Folder","folder":"{}","@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior":"rename"});
headerMap = Map();
headerMap.putAll({"Content-Type":"application/json"});
r = invokeurl
[
url :"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children"
type :POST
parameters:callMap.toString()
headers:headerMap
connection:"onedrive"
];
info r;
```

but gives the error "code": "BadRequest","message": "Property folder in payload has a value that does not match schema."
Anyone have a solution?

Comment: No, I wrote according to the corrections and the error still appears

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your definition of `folder` is `"{}"` (i.e. a string), when it should be `{}` (i.e. an object).

Answer (score 0):

```
callMap = Map();
callMap.putAll({"name":"New Folder","folder":{ "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.folder" },"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior":"rename"});
headerMap = Map();
headerMap.putAll({"Content-Type":"application/json"});
r = invokeurl
[
    url :"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children"
    type :POST
    parameters:callMap.toString()
    headers:headerMap
    connection:"onedrive"
];
info r;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).